# How to convert Icelandic months names to English moths names?

Tags: php, regex, date, datetime

I have some date variables that contain Icelandic months names like:

```
$date = '27. júní 2018 04:53'
```

I want to compare between dates, But when I try that:

```
strtotime('27. júní 2018 04:53');
```

I get blank result.

And when I try:

```
new DateTime('27. júní 2018 04:53');
```

I get an error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'DateTime::__construct(): 
Failed to parse time string (27. júní 2018 04:53) at position 0 (2): 
Unexpected character'    
Stack trace: #0: DateTime->__construct('27. j\xC3\xBAn\xC3\xAD 2018...') #1 {main} thrown
```

Is there is a way to translate or convert these months names to English months names?

Answer (score 0):

I came up wit this, it required `php7.0-intl` to be installed:

```
<?php
$input     = '27. júní 2018 04:53';
$locale    = 'is_IS';
$date_type = IntlDateFormatter::FULL;
$time_type = IntlDateFormatter::FULL;
$timezone  = 'Atlantic/Reykjavik';
$calendar  = IntlDateFormatter::GREGORIAN;
$pattern   = 'd. MMMM yyyy HH:ss'; // see http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/datetime

$formatter = new IntlDateFormatter($locale, $date_type, $time_type, $timezone, $calendar, $pattern);
$timestamp = $formatter->parse($input);

$output = DateTime::createFromFormat('U', $timestamp)->format('d F Y H:i:s');
echo $output;
```

This gives you:

```
27 June 2018 04:00:53
```

Hope this helps.